# Suppose that a cube is inscribed in a sphere of radius one. What is the volume of the cube? my reasoning vs answer

Tags: elementary-number-theory, vector-spaces, contest-math

Now my reasoning is that, s^2 + s^2 = 2^2, where s is the side of the cube, giving, s^3 = 2 sqrt 2. But the answer and explanation here is different: http://math.acadiau.ca/aumc/hints4.pdf

how is the distance from the center to the corner that? sqrt(3(s/2)^2) ?

Comment: Note that you are in three dimensions, not two - and the diameter is the long diagonal of the cube not a face diagonal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply Pythagoras twice: The face diagonal $d$ of a cube of side length $a$ can be found from $d^2=a^2+a^2$, the *spacial* diagonal $D$ can then be found from $D^2=d^2+a^2$.